# Delete Product on Amazon MWS

Tags: xml, amazon-mws

I want to delete multiple child products with Amazon MWS with this feed:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" ?>
            <AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
              <Header>
                <DocumentVersion>1.02</DocumentVersion>
                <MerchantIdentifier>$MerchantIdentifier</MerchantIdentifier>
              </Header>
              <MessageType>Product</MessageType>
              <PurgeAndReplace>false</PurgeAndReplace>
              <Message>
                <MessageID>1</MessageID>
                <OperationType>Delete</OperationType>
                <Product>
                  <SKU>24.desk.150x60.schwarz</SKU>
                </Product>
                <MessageID>2</MessageID>
                <OperationType>Delete</OperationType>
                <Product>
                  <SKU>24.desk.180x100.weiss</SKU>
                </Product>
              </Message>
            </AmazonEnvelope>
```

but the response is "No child element is expected at this point." Is it not possible to delete multiple childs?

the childs are from a parent product I deleted before.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake. Every message needs his own message-Tag.